# Comparing Javascript Symbols not working

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I am learning the Symbol feature of ES6.

So in node, I write the following (in Typescript actually).  It compiles fine, but the console logs "Not found"  What am I doing wrong?  It seems to me that it ought to work.

This example comes from [this](https://www.keithcirkel.co.uk/metaprogramming-in-es6-symbols/) article

```
"use strict"

var levels = {
    DEBUG: Symbol('debug'),
    INFO: Symbol('info'),
    WARN: Symbol('warn'),
};
function log(level: Symbol, message)
{
    switch(level)
    {
        case Symbol.for('debug'):
            console.log(`Debug Message: ${message}`);
            break;

        case Symbol.for('info'):
            console.log(`Info Message: ${message}`);
            break;

        case Symbol.for('warn'):
            console.log(`Warn Message: ${message}`);
            break;

        default:
            console.log("Not found");
    }
}


log(levels.DEBUG, 'debug message');
log(levels.INFO, 'info message');
```

**Update**

As pointed out in the accepted answer, this will work:

```
var levels = {
    DEBUG: Symbol.for('debug'),
    INFO: Symbol.for('info'),
    WARN: Symbol.for('warn')
};
function log(level: Symbol, message)
{
    switch(level)
    {
        case Symbol.for('debug'):
            console.log(`Debug Message: ${message}`);
            break;

        case Symbol.for('info'):
            console.log(`Info Message: ${message}`);
            break;

        case Symbol.for('warn'):
            console.log(`Warn Message: ${message}`);
            break;

        default:
            console.log("Not found");
    }
}


log(levels.DEBUG, 'debug message');
log(levels.INFO, 'info message');
```

**Second Update**

Also, as pointed out by @Felix Kling, this is even better:

```
var levels = {
    DEBUG: Symbol('debug'),
    INFO: Symbol('info'),
    WARN: Symbol('warn')
};
function log(level: Symbol, message)
{
    switch(level)
    {
        case levels.DEBUG:
            console.log(`Debug Message: ${message}`);
            break;

        case levels.INFO:
            console.log(`Info Message: ${message}`);
            break;

        case levels.WARN:
            console.log(`Warn Message: ${message}`);
            break;

        default:
            console.log("Not found");
    }
}
```

Comment: You have answers for why it doesn't work. However, I'd recommend to not use `Symbol.for` and do `case levels.DEBUG:` instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Symbol('somestring');
```

Doesn't create a global Symbol.

```
Symbol.for('somestring');
```

Either gets a previously defined global symbol or creates a new global symbol.

Therefore, the first time you check your `case` statements, you're creating new symbols rather than checking against your previously defined symbols.

If you use `Symbol.for('somestring')` when defining the symbols in the first place, they'll be found when you check them later.

Answer (score 3):

The reason is because `Symbol('debug') !== Symbol.for('debug')`.

You need to write:

```
var levels = {
  DEBUG: Symbol.for('debug'),
  INFO: Symbol.for('info'),
  WARN: Symbol.for('warn'),
};
```

[MDN: Symbol](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Symbol):

> The above syntax using the `Symbol()` function will **not** create a **global** symbol that is available in your whole codebase. To create symbols available across files and even across realms (each of which has its own global scope), use the methods `Symbol.for()` and `Symbol.keyFor()` to set and retrieve symbols from the global symbol registry.

Answer (score 3):

Every call to Symbol creates a new instance of a Symbol.

So Symbol('foo') === Symbol('foo') is false.

The Symbol.for method searches for a given key. If the key is not found it will be created. Otherwise it returns the already defined value.

```
"use strict"

var levels = {
    DEBUG: Symbol.for('debug'),
    INFO: Symbol.for('info'),
    WARN: Symbol.for('warn'),
};
function log(level, message)
{
    switch(level)
    {
        case Symbol.for('debug'):
            console.log(`Debug Message: ${message}`);
            break;

        case Symbol.for('info'):
            console.log(`Info Message: ${message}`);
            break;

        case Symbol.for('warn'):
            console.log(`Warn Message: ${message}`);
            break;

        default:
            console.log("Not found");
    }
}


log(levels.DEBUG, 'debug message');
log(levels.INFO, 'info message');
```